# Nested implicit cursor not clearin data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an oracle pl/sql anonymous block with an implicit cursor in a for loop that is nested on a for loop in this way:

```
FOR secuence IN 1..3 LOOP
  FOR registro_notificacion IN (
             SELECT 'data' FROM my_table WHERE my_table.column1=secuence)
      LOOP
         --work with data
  END LOOP; END LOOP;
```

The problems occurs when I have values returned on `secuence=1` and empty on the others because for some reason the implicit cursor doesn´t `clean` itself.
So, on the `secuence=2` im suposed to don't do nothing because there is no data, but for some reason it still have the data returned on the first loop `(secuence=1)`.

Should I declare and explicit cursor to close at the end of every iteration? Although I consider to use 3 for loops, one for every `secuence` value but that its not the idea I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use cursor for-loops all the time and have never seen the situation you describe. The only thing I can think is that you have a variable named `secuence` declared elsewhere in your program that happens to be set to 1. In this case, the PL/SQL compiler may be choosing to use the global variable `secuence` rather than the loop-control variable `secuence` when generating the SQL statement. A good rule of thumb is to use a unique name for each loop-control variable.

However, you can get rid of the `FOR secuence...` loop entirely by using:

```
FOR registro_notificacion IN (SELECT 'data'
                                FROM my_table
                                WHERE my_table.column1 BETWEEN 1 AND 3
                                ORDER BY my_table.column1)
LOOP
     --work with data
END LOOP;
```

Opening one cursor is generally less costly than opening three cursors.

Best of luck.

Comment: You where right, i was trying to make some kind of report from this anonymous block and i think i was just drowing on a glass of water. I think i can work with this aproach, thank you :)